# Android : What kind of encryption do I choose to send my data safely to an app using WCF?

Tags: java, android, wcf, encryption, aes

I have a project where I need to connect an Android App to an ERP that uses WCF, IIS (Internet Information Services), Active Directory and Role Based Scurity.

There are thus a lot of security options allready included by default like basicHttpBinding which allows the use of certificates and HTTPS and so on.

The one thing I haven't decided yet is what data encryption I'll use to secure the data when it travels from the app to the ERP. I have read that there is a Java AES library that can be used, then again I also read that somebody could also decrypt the packages if he or she intercepts them.

I was wondering two things:

- Is there a "Best Practice" concerning data encryption on mobile apps, since the computing power is not as strong as a computer's and the message can't be too heavy or long to decrypt since this would slow down the app which we do not want of course.
- I was actually thinking about using some kind of PGP public key where the public key is in the Android Devices and the private Key is in the ERP but maybe this is not a smart or even a very secure way to do it?

Then again.. since I'll be using TLS, maybe I don't need to encrypt my Data and it's secure enough?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android is pretty much strait forward with their security protocols.

What you can do is use this function and find the protocol you would like to use:

```
Provider[] providers = Security.getProviders();
for (Provider provider : providers) {
    for (Object entry : provider.keySet()) {
        String name = String.valueOf(entry);
        if (name.startsWith("Cipher")) {
            Log.d("Cipher", "Supports: " + name.substring(7));
        }
    }
}
```

any one of those is a standart protocol and can be used both on the client side and the server side.

good luck.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for that code, I managed to get that long list. There are a lot of Password Based encryption as well as different kinds of AES and DES. Still, now that I know what my options are and I have a much better idea of how to integrate them, I wonder which one will be the best for me? Should I just use AES, Password based encryption with AES or TRIPLE DES or RC4 or use OPENSSSL with 26BIT AES...

Comment: Note that the app will not be used by thousands of users and the data is not critical, still, a minimum of security must be implemented.

Comment: you have to think about the time that it will take your server to decrypt and encrypt every packet that is sent to the device. I would say that if you're looking for minimal security use a simple 128BIT AES and send the data over https

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll do that then :)